# How to implement Facebook Like in non-Javascript environments

Tags: facebook, mobile, facebook-graph-api

I am working in mobile environments that do not support Javascript. Is it possible to add Facebook Like functionality to a page, probably doing server-side requests to Facebook?

For a more detailed example, if I go to http://ogp.me/, there is a Like button towards the bottom of the page. Clicking on that uses Javascript, optionally signing into Facebook if the relevant cookies aren't there.

I want to provide the same functionality, but without using Javascript (clue: need to support Blackberry browsers).

My intention was to use OAuth 2.0 with standard redirects, to get an access token with which to call the Graph API.

Once I have an access token, I was expecting something like

```
curl https://graph.facebook.com/me/likes?access_token={a-valid-access-token}&category=Website&url={url-encoding-of-url-to-like}
```

where the access token has the publish_stream permission granted to it. So to be more explicit:

```
curl https://graph.facebook.com/me/likes?access_token={a-valid-access-token}&category=Website&url=http%3A%2F%2Fogp.me%2F
```

That attempt returns me a 403 response, and I've not found anything else in the [fine manual](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The graph api does allow you to like a graph object (see [Graph API Docs / Publishing](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/#publishing)) using:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/OBJECT_ID/likes
```

However the graph object must have an existing *likes* connection - and there's currently no way of creating such a connection via the graph api.

But if the like connection already exists you can get the pages graph object id using FQL:

```
SELECT id FROM object_url WHERE url='http://youtargeturl.lnk'
```

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'm thinking too. I was wondering if there's a way of creating a Page if it doesn't already exist, and then POSTing to the likes collection of the Page, but I haven't seen a way of creating a Page.

Comment: Do you want to create either a Facebook Fan OR Profile page?

Comment: I've updated the question, which hopefully explains more fully what I'm trying to accomplish.

Comment: What kind of graph object are you trying to like?

Comment: Any number of pages on a site that I'm creating.

Comment: You problem is still that it is not possible to create a like connection programmatically.

Comment: @jBit let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2101/discussion-between-jabley-and-jbit)